# how to define static constants in typescript and angular

Tags: angular, typescript, static, constants

I have bunch of constants which are business related and I have to store them in Angular.Something like below

```
STUDENT_NAMES= ["JOHN","BOB","NICK"]
TEACHER_NAME = ["HARRY","CHRIS"]
 SCHOOL_CODE = [100,102,107];
```

I have a lot of them and they are kind of static ..I need  them in most of my service classes.
What is the best place to store them? Should i create a interface and let my service class inherit them?
In java , we define a class of public static final constants and other classes uses them.Like this , what is the typescript way?

Answer (score 66):

Define an abstract class for your constants:

```
export abstract class Constants {
  static readonly STUDENT_NAMES = ["JOHN", "BOB", "NICK"];
  static readonly TEACHER_NAME = ["HARRY", "CHRIS"];
  static readonly SCHOOL_CODE = [100, 102, 107];
}
```

(Edit: Types `string[]` and `number[]` are inferred by TS)

Then include this class whereever needed with `import { Constants } from '...';` and use its values with `const names: string[] = Constants.STUDENT_NAMES;`

Regarding the naming I agree with @AdrianBrand to prefer names like `studentNames`, `teacherNames` and `schoolCodes`.

**Edit:** TypeScript 3.4 introduced so called [`const` assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions), which might also be suited:

```
export const constants = {
  studentNames: ["JOHN", "BOB", "NICK"],
  ...
} as const;
```

Comment: Best way to create constants. Thanks.

Comment: abstract not really needed though imo - out of interest why use abstract here? Shoudnt devs update the source instead of adding more constants elsewere?

Comment: @dalcam Yes, `abstract` is indeed not needed per se. But I like the idea not being able to instantiate `Constants`.

Answer (score 22):

You put them in a TypeScript file and import them where needed.

```
export const STUDENT_NAMES: string[] = ["JOHN","BOB","NICK"];
```

Put it in student-names.ts

```
import { STUDENT_NAMES } from './path/cosnstants/student-names';
```

where you need it.

Personally I would name them studentNames and not STUDENT_NAMES but that is a matter of taste.

Answer (score 10):

You can create a TS file `constants.ts` that contains all your constants :

```
export const constants = {
   STUDENT_NAMES: ["JOHN","BOB","NICK"],
   TEACHER_NAME: ["HARRY","CHRIS"],
   SCHOOL_CODE: [100,102,107]
};
```

Then whenever you need a constant you can call it like this code bellow:

```
let studentsNames : any = constants.STUDENT_NAMES;
```

Regards,

Comment: But then you are not explicitly declaring the types of the constants, so it isn't very typescripty, and they aren't constant - they can be reassigned.

Answer (score 0):

you could try enums,  this will allow you to define a set of named constants. [Refer to this document.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html)

```
enum Constants {
    STUDENT_NAMES= ["JOHN","BOB","NICK"]
    TEACHER_NAME = ["HARRY","CHRIS"]
    SCHOOL_CODE = [100,102,107];
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Add all your constants in `environment.ts` file - this is the best practice and there will be no change in the values basd on the environment specific

Add both in `environment.ts` and `environment.prod.ts` - this will be your global object and can be accessed at any level

Importing will be same as importing an interface or any class
Thanks - Happy coding

Comment: I would only recommend using environment variables for things that change between dev, test and prod environments like api endpoints, I would not pollute it with every constant in your application.

Comment: Then you can export a separate const. File and get the data